# Symbolise GeoJSON by date ranges using MapBox / CartoDB / Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, geojson, cartodb

I have a GeoJSON file of fly tip incidents that have happened over the last year which is updated regularly.

I am looking for a solution where I can add this data onto a map and symbolise it to show one marker for incidents that have happened over the last month, another for between 1 and 3 months, and a final marker for any incidents from over 3 months ago.

I have thought about using one of MapBox, CartoDB or Leaflet, do these libraries have the capabilities to be able to style data in this way? I want to keep my data locally so do not want to load it into an online account.

I'd like to know if this can be done with one of the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MapBox and CartoDB services are built onto Leaflet library. You can use them for everything (including uploading your data), or just for the background map. So even with them you can keep your data locally.

Leaflet is the sure choice for total control of your data, as you will be doing all the operations yourself.

Note that you also have other libraries that provide you with the same control with that respect, like OpenLayers, and D3 to some extent.

As for displaying different markers based on age of your data, there is no special difficulty in doing so.